# Convert date to mysql format in java and pass it to function

Tags: java, mysql

I want to filter orders based on dates. 
My code is,

```
    if ( filterObject != null ) {
        if ( !AgileUtil.isEmpty( filterObject.getCustid() ) ) {
            query.append( "AND ORD.CUSTID = '" ).append( filterObject.getCustid() ).append( "' " );
        }
        if ( !AgileUtil.isEmpty( filterObject.getPid() ) ) {
            query.append( "AND ORD.OID IN ( SELECT OD.OID FROM ORDERDETAIL OD WHERE ORD.OID = OD.OID AND OD.PID = '" )
            .append( filterObject.getPid() )
            .append( "' ) " );
        }
        if ( filterObject.getFromDate() != null ) {
            //AppConstants.DATEFORMAT.format( obj.getCreated() );

            query.append( "AND ORD.OID IN(SELECT OD.OID FROM ORDERDETAIL OD WHERE ORD.OID = OD.OID AND OD.CREATED > FROMDATE '" )
            .append( filterObject.getFromDate() )
            .append( "' " );

        }
        if ( filterObject.getToDate() != null ) {

            query.append( "AND ORD.OID IN(SELECT OD.OID FROM ORDERDETAIL OD WHERE ORD.OID = OD.OID AND OD.CREATED < TODATE '" )
            .append( filterObject.getToDate() )
            .append( "' " );
        }
        if ( ( filterObject.getFromDate() != null ) && ( filterObject.getToDate() != null ) ) {
            query.append( "AND ORD.OID IN(SELECT OD.OID FROM ORDERDETAIL OD WHERE ORD.OID = OD.OID AND OD.CREATED BETWEEN FROMDATE AND TODATE '" )
                .append( filterObject.getFromDate() );
        }
        if ( filterObject.getAmount() != null ) {
            query.append( "AND ORD.TOTAL = " ).append( filterObject.getAmount() );
        }
    }
```

Now the main question in front of me is how can I convert date like `31/08/2015` to mysql format `0000-00-00` and pass it to `filterObject.getFromDate()`,`filterObject.getToDate()` for comparison this date with table column 'CREATED' in database.

Comment: [Use Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and `java.sql.Date` and let the driver deal with it

Comment: Google link : [convert java date to mysql date](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=convert+java+date+to+mysql+date&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ytnnVdPvBtWNuASk1LtI)

Comment: Dude.  First google for 'SQL Injection Attack', then chuckle at http://xkcd.com/327/, then figure out how to do this with a PreparedStatement which allows you to just use a Java Date object directly independent of whatever database you are on.

Comment: @BobKuhar Thank you. That xkcd made my day.